# Integrability of functions restricted to lower dimension objects like curves.

Tags: analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $f(x,y)$ be in $L^p(\mathbb{R^2})$. Suppose I define a new function $\mathring{f}$ by 
$$
\mathring{f}(x) = f(x,\phi(x)) 
$$ for some suitable real valued smooth function $\phi$. What can I say about the integrability of $\mathring{f}$?

Are there any suitable conditions that one can impose on $\phi$ so that $\mathring{f}$ is in $L^q(\mathbb{R})$ for any $q$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure how relevant this is, but the integrability of $\mathring{f}$ is going to depend on which representative you pick for $f$ in its equivalence class in $L^2$. For example, let $\tilde{f} = c >0$  on the graph of $\phi$ and let it agree with $f$ everywhere else. Then $f$ and $\tilde{f}$ are in the same equivalence class in $L^2$ since the graph of $\phi$ is measure zero in the plane, but then $\mathring{\tilde{f}} \notin L^q$ for any finite $q$.